# Track any changes of articles (Mediawiki 1.23)

Tags: php, hook, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm new in Mediawiki.

I have database records linked to some elements of articles content. Data in database are fully dependent on content of the articles and must be updated when corresponding elements are changed. Some [mediawiki hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) provide part of required functionality, but I'm not sure that it's right solution, because I must use few different hooks for same task and it looks too complicated in trivial situation like this.

How can I do this by most appropriate way?

I'm using page_id for linking to articles inside database. Is it right in this case?

What mediawiki hooks I must use for all situation where database must be updated? Currently I want using this:

- ArticleInsertComplete
- ArticleDeleteComplete
- ArticleRevisionUndeleted
- PageContentSaveComplete
- ArticleRollbackComplete
- ArticleMergeComplete

Or how can I catch any recentchanges?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there isn't a single hook to run your code for any change which might happen to a page. This is for two related reasons:

1. there are countless paths which might alter a page: not all of them are in core, some are provided by extensions; changes might come from another page (e.g. a template); or even another wiki (e.g. a file repository, or even a template you scary-transclude);
2. it's not a good idea to deal with all cases in the same way, because some updates can be safely ignored, others can kill your wiki if done in bulk and should be delayed in the job queue, others must be run immediately.

So, yes, you have to find out all the hooks (your list is already a good one, for core; needs to be revised with every extension you install). If the kind of update you need is always the same, you can just [attach](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) the same function to all hooks, so the duplication is minimal.